# How can I convert string to dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I got a string like below, How can I convert it to dict ?

```
'{"x":0.4070095121860504,"y":21.447710037231445,"z":14.341651916503906},
{"x":0.4153441786766052,"y":20.767126083374023,"z":13.665939331054688},
{"x":1.1504541635513306,"y":21.594528198242188,"z":14.19514274597168},
{"x":-0.3110668659210205,"y":21.66669273376465,"z":14.237279891967773}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like JSON except for a missing `[` at the start and a `]` at the end.

You can use something like:

```
import json
data = json.loads("[" + mystring + "]")
```

the result will be a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

Use `json.loads()` to convert it dictionary. For example:

```
In [24]: st
Out[24]: '{"K1": "v1", "K2": "\\nv2"}'

In [25]: json.loads(st)
Out[25]: {'K1': 'v1', 'K2': '\nv2'}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use  `ast.literal_eval` after you add `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end :

```
from ast import literal_eval

list_dicts = literal_eval(f'[{s}]')
list_dicts
```

output:

```
[{'x': 0.4070095121860504, 'y': 21.447710037231445, 'z': 14.341651916503906},
 {'x': 0.4153441786766052, 'y': 20.767126083374023, 'z': 13.665939331054688},
 {'x': 1.1504541635513306, 'y': 21.594528198242188, 'z': 14.19514274597168},
 {'x': -0.3110668659210205, 'y': 21.66669273376465, 'z': 14.237279891967773}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use json library:

```
import json
str1 =' your dict'
dict1 = json.loads(str1)
```

So here:

```
str1 = '[{"x":0.4070095121860504,"y":21.447710037231445,"z":14.341651916503906},{"x":0.4153441786766052,"y":20.767126083374023,"z":13.665939331054688},{"x":1.1504541635513306,"y":21.594528198242188,"z":14.19514274597168},{"x":-0.3110668659210205,"y":21.66669273376465,"z":14.237279891967773}]'
import json
dict1 = json.loads(str1)
```

You can also use :

```
eval(str1)
```

But usage of eval is not recommended.
You string has multiple dictionary. So either :

```
str1 = '{' + your string + '}'
```

Or:

```
str1 = '(' + your string + ')'
```

or similarily, a list:

```
str1 = '[' + your multiple duct string + ']'
```

Comment: `jain.loads`? Did you try running this code?